# cannot read repomd.xml

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I am trying to install additional packages from a RHEL-8 installation DVD on a server that is not connected to the internet. I mounted the DVD ISO on `/mnt/cdrom`. I have the following in my `/etc/yum.repos.d/baseos.repo` file:

```
[baseos]
name=BaseOs_Repository
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/BaseOs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

When I try to install a package, I get the following error:

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'baseos':
  - Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file for file:///mnt/cdrom/BaseOs/repodata/repomd.xml [Couldn't open file /mnt/cdrom/BaseOs/repodata/repomd.xml]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

The file exists and has the correct permissions:

```
[root@ngsv8 repodata]# ls -lh /mnt/cdrom/BaseOS/repodata/
total 3.1M
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  75K Oct 13  2021 059387f37531102607f15430a20c0a02737d3917295288657c3dc2bf3b4d3388-comps-BaseOS.x86_64.xml.gz
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 1.3M Oct 13  2021 605f660b7c02389f9dc05b018bed8a414cc6f354eb0748aa55efc31c9e4c2298-filelists.xml.gz
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 1.1M Oct 13  2021 650308603c7c00e2f2265686d472750875
51b6326e7a1077d93f3f317e0e8cce-primary.xml.gz
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 444K Oct 13  2021 67ea1c69bf2d3ff30e0aa59fd2ccd7890decdf1f4fb6acb305f9e027551fd00f-other.xml.gz
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 301K Oct 13  2021 7a3932d707bf3b84d0cccbe2a5382ad04613ef4e2308a95aef2c16e999702119-comps-BaseOS.x86_64.xml
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 1.6K Oct 13  2021 ee6f2ed466e70c8ee4dd48d8aa3897707349e31e3f546a82e121cc53cc82d8a8-productid.gz
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 2.2K Oct 13  2021 productid
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 2.8K Oct 13  2021 repomd.xml
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 2.2K Oct 13  2021 TRANS.TBL
```

I have a similar `.repo` file for the `AppStream/` subdirectory of the installation DVD and it appears to work since it doesn't spit any error messages.  I tried copying the `appstream.repo` to `baseos.repo` and changed all the references from `appstream` to `baseos` just in case I had a typo that I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo - `BaseOs` vs `BaseOS`. Fix your repo file to match the DVD filesystem.

Here's your error message:

```
Couldn't open file /mnt/cdrom/BaseOs/repodata/repomd.xml
```

Here's the `ls` command:

```
ls -lh /mnt/cdrom/BaseOS/repodata/
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it was a typo; but, I just couldn't see it.  I should stop hitting the <tab> key when I am trying to find these problems.